# AssertionError: Fields in 'groupby' must be regular database-persisted fields in openerp

Tags: openerp-7

I am new to openerp, When I am trying to create a new asset and click on the `Entries` button. The server is throwing the following error.

```
AssertionError: Fields in 'groupby' must be regular database-persisted
fields (no function or related fields), or function fields with store=True
```

How to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

Either a module you created/modified, or one you installed, is trying to sort the records by using a virtual field.  Either fix the field to be a normal field, or remove it from the `groupby` clause (or uninstall the module).